# How could we show that the set is equal to the empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to show that the intersection of any inductive set is empty since every inductive set contains the empty set.

I thought that we could do it like that:

We know that $B$ is an inductive set. So:

$$\varnothing \in B \wedge \forall x(x \in B \rightarrow x' \in B)$$

$$y \in \bigcap B \leftrightarrow \forall b \in B: y \in b$$

Since $\varnothing \in B$ we get that $y \in \bigcap B \leftrightarrow y \in \varnothing$.

But since there is no $y$ such that $y \in \varnothing$ we conclude that we cannot find a $y$ such that $y \in \bigcap B$.

But it isn't right, since we cannot just take one set to get the equivalence, right?

How else could we do this?

Comment: What is $x'$ in this $x' \in B$? Or is this supposed to be $\forall x' \in x: x' \in B$ or equivalently $x \subseteq B$?

Comment: With $x'$ I mean the next element of $x$. $x'=x \cup \{x\}$. @Thorsten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks right. So let me reorder your argument:

Now your argument: we know $\emptyset \in B$. So for an arbitrary $y$ we have two directions to prove:

- if $y\in \bigcap B$ it follows $y \in \emptyset$ (By your property for $\bigcap$).
- if we have $y\in \emptyset$, then we have a contradictory assumption (by the definition of the emptyset), and so we have $y \in \bigcap B$ in particular.

So in total: $\forall y (y \in \bigcap B \leftrightarrow y \in \emptyset)$. And by the axiom of extensionality, we have $\bigcap B = \emptyset$.

Alternatively you can prove it as follows: We know that the emptyset $\emptyset$ is the unique set with the property $\forall y(y\not\in \emptyset)$. Assume there is an element $y \in \bigcap B$, so we have $y \in \emptyset \in B$ by the property of $\bigcap B$, a contradiction. So $\forall y(y\not\in \bigcap B)$, and $\bigcap B = \emptyset$ by uniqueness.

**EDIT:** And to answer the title question "How could we show that the set is equal to the empty set?": You show that a set $x$ is equal to the emptyset by proving that $\forall y. (y\not\in x)$.

Comment: Thorsten Could you explain me further how we could prove using the property of $\bigcap$ that if $y \in \bigcap B$ then we have that $y \in \varnothing$?

Comment: You already stated the property $\forall x\ (x \in \bigcap B \leftrightarrow \forall b \in B: x \in b)$. So instantiate the outer quantifier with $y$, take the direction from left to right and instantiate the right quantifier with $\emptyset$, and you get: $y \in \bigcap B \rightarrow y \in \emptyset$.

Answer (score -4):

Counterexample: Consider $N = 29$ and $M = 20$ with $N \cap M = 20$

Comment: This won't be the intersection of any inductive set but the intersection of a set of inductive sets, or am I wrong?

Comment: You very well said "the intersection of any inductive set is empty" but I just gave you two inductive sets and their (non-empty) intersection.

You have to specify: the intersection of any inductive set *with what other set*?

Comment: In your example, we have two inductive sets, $N$ and $M$, and in order to find their intersection we consider a set $K=\{N,M\}$ and find $\bigcap K$. So we find the intersection of a set of inductive sets. But I want to show that $\bigcap B$ where $B$, is not a set of inductive sets but an inductive set is the empty set.

Comment: So you're saying an inductive set is the empty set?

To have an intersection, you must have two sets. Taking the intersection of one set alone won't do...

Comment: In mathematics, the intersection A ∩ B of two sets A and B is the set that contains all elements of A that also belong to B (or equivalently, all elements of B that also belong to A), but no other elements

Comment: So if we have the intersection of one inductive set, it is equal to the set?

Comment: @Don Larynx $\bigcap B=\bigcap_{A\in B} A$.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski So it doesn't hold that $\bigcap B=\varnothing$, right? But $\bigcap B=B$ ? If so, it would never be equal to $\varnothing$, or am I wrong?

Comment: The point is, you need two sets. Otherwise, $B$ is either the empty set since you can have the intersection of the empty set with the empty set **OR** composed of another set equal to itself which you haven't defined.

Comment: @DonLarynx According to my notes, we can only take the general intersection at non-empty sets. Does thin mean that $\bigcap B$ cannot be the empty set?

Comment: @Don Not quite. In set theory, everything is a set, so the elements of a set are sets as well, and if $ A $ is a non-empty set, $\bigcap A $ is defined. There is no need to have two sets, or to consider the intersection of an inductive set *with* something else.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo And does it hold that $\bigcap B=B$ and that it cannot be the empty set? :/

Comment: @Andres: As I said: Either $B$ is the empty set or $B$ is a non-empty set, and in that case, its arbitrary intersection is empty. I hope this answers your question, evinda

Comment: @DonLarynx How can it be the empty set?

Comment: @evinda $\bigcap B$ can be the empty set, if none of the elements of $B$ have a common element. For example if $\emptyset\in B$ then $\bigcap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski But each inductive set does contain $\varnothing$. So it holds that $\bigcap B=\varnothing$, right?

Comment: Yes, if your definition of inductive set requires that it has the empty set as an element $\bigcap B=\emptyset$ is true.